# cannot find the ServiceClient[from metadata]

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to fix this WCF service to populate a dropdownlist.  The only problem I got is I cannot find the DoctorDetail[from Metadata] which is suppose to be generate.  Here is the code from Apointement.aspx.cs

```
private List<DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient> DoctorDetail()
{
    DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient client = new 
    DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient();

    DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient[] doctors = client.**DoctorDetail()**; **<== error

    return doctors.ToList();
}
```

> The error is the following:  Error 4   'DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient' does not contain a definition for 'DoctorDetail' and no extension method 'DoctorDetail' accepting a first argument of type 'DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Doctor\pages\Apointement.aspx.cs    189

The DoctorService.cs  `WebService`

```
public class DoctorService : IDoctorService
{
    public List<Doctor>  DoctorDetail()    

    {
        using (DoctorDataContext db = new DoctorDataContext())
        {
            return (from doctor in db.Doctors

                select new  Doctor()    
                {
                    Id = doctor.Id,
                    Doctor_name = doctor.Doctor_name
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

doctor.cs

```
public class DoctorDetail
{
    private int id;
    private string doctor_name;

    public DoctorDetail()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get { return this.id; } set { this.id = value; } }
    public string Doctor_name { get { return this.doctor_name; } set { this.doctor_name = value;   
    } }

}
```

I am adding the DoctorServiceClient[from metadata]

```
namespace DoctorServiceReference
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public class DoctorServiceClient : ClientBase<IDoctorService>, IDoctorService
    {
        public DoctorServiceClient();
        public DoctorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName);
        public DoctorServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
        public DoctorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress 
               remoteAddress);
        public DoctorServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress);

        public Doctor[] DoctorDetail();
        public Task<Doctor[]> DoctorDetailAsync();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely a guess but it looks like `DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient` refers to a class that would be generated by Add Service Reference in Visual Studio or the SvcUtil.EXE utility. Try something like: `List<DoctorServiceReference.DoctorDetail>` as the list type. It is likely the generated proxy is in the `DoctorServiceReference` namespace.

Comment: I finally was able to Update the Web/Services by exiting Visual Studio and re-open it.  I right click on App_WebReferences to Update Web/Service References.  The error is still there and the error message is Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'DoctorServiceReference.Doctor[]' to 'DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient[]' C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\DoctorApt\pages\Apointement.aspx.cs

Comment: Do you see what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

service method is
public List  DoctorDetail()

and the call from client proxy is
DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient[] doctors = client.DoctorDetail()

Comment: I finally was able to Update the Web/Services by exiting Visual Studio and re-open it. I right click on App_WebReferences to Update Web/Service References. The error is still there and the error message is Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'DoctorServiceReference.Doctor[]' to 'DoctorServiceReference.DoctorServiceClient[]' C:\Users\SP_Admin\Documents\Visua‌​l Studio 2013\WebSites\DoctorApt\pages\Apointement.aspx.cs –

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I wasn't able to generate the Update Web/Service References.  I close everything in VS and re-open it.  then I was able to perform the Update Web/Service References.  The ServiceClient Metadata were there after.